# How to filter items of combobox in tableview using QSqlRelationalTableModel?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview, qcombobox

I have a tableview that is set as below:

```
self.table = QTableView()  
self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)  
self.model.setTable('main')
self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
self.model.setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("Names", "nameOfCm", "nameOfCm"))
self.model.setRelation(2, QSqlRelation("Types", "type_IDs", "typeOfCm"))
self.model.setRelation(8, QSqlRelation("Places", "placeName", "placeName"))
self.model.select()   
self.table.setModel(self.model)
self.table.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.table))
```

By using QSqlRelationalDelegate I have comboboxes in some columns of the table.

Column No:1 is the name of some electronic components (like Transistor Or IC etc.).

Column No:2 is the type of this electronic components (For example for Transistor I have PNP, NPN etc. For IC I have Op-Amp, Micro and so on).

When I click on combobox in column "type" it shows all type of electronic components no matter what I have selected in combobox column "name".
I want to filter these items in such a way that only related items for combobox "name" show in the combobox "type".

For example If I choose transistor from  "name", combobox "type" shows: NPN, PNP. And if I choose IC, combobox "type" shows: Micro, Op_Amp.

This is simplified code:

```
 import sys
 from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
 from PyQt5.QtSql import *

connectDB = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
connectDB.setDatabaseName('test.db')
connectDB.open()
query = QSqlQuery()
createNameTable='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Names" ("nameOfCm" TEXT,   PRIMARY KEY("nameOfCm"))'
createTypeTable='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Types" ("type_IDs" TEXT,   "typeOfCm"  TEXT,PRIMARY KEY("type_IDs"))'
createMainTable='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main" ("partnumber" TEXT,"name" TEXT,"type" TEXT,PRIMARY KEY("partnumber"))'

query.exec(createNameTable)
query.exec(createTypeTable)
query.exec(createMainTable)
query.exec("INSERT INTO Names (nameOfCm) VALUEs ('IC')")
query.exec("INSERT INTO Names (nameOfCm) VALUEs ('Transistor')")
query.exec("INSERT INTO Types (type_IDs,typeOfCm) VALUEs ('Transistor1','NPN')")
query.exec("INSERT INTO Types (type_IDs,typeOfCm) VALUEs ('Transistor2','PNP')")
query.exec("INSERT INTO Types (type_IDs,typeOfCm) VALUEs ('IC1','Op_AMP')")
query.exec("INSERT INTO Types (type_IDs,typeOfCm) VALUEs ('IC2','Micro')")

class main (QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(main,self).__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle('My Electronic Inventory v: 0.1')
    self.setGeometry(10, 10, 400 , 500)
    self.UI()
    self.show()        
    self.databaseIsConect()

def UI(self):

    self.mainCentralWidget =        QWidget()
    self.mainLayout =               QVBoxLayout()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainCentralWidget)
    self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    self.newComponentButton=         QPushButton("Add component")
    self.newComponentButton.clicked.connect(self.newComponentButtonClicked)

    self.table=   QTableView()  
    self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self) 
    self.model.setTable('main')
    self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
    self.model.setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("Names", "nameOfCm", "nameOfCm"))
    self.model.setRelation(2, QSqlRelation("Types", "type_IDs", "typeOfCm"))
    self.model.select()   
    self.table.setModel(self.model)
    self.table.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.table))
    self.table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked|QAbstractItemView.AnyKeyPressed)
    self.model.setHeaderData(0,Qt.Horizontal,('Part Number'))
    self.model.setHeaderData(1,Qt.Horizontal,('Name'))
    self.model.setHeaderData(2,Qt.Horizontal,('Type'))

    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.newComponentButton)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.table)

def databaseIsConect(self):
    if connectDB.isOpen():
        print("Databsae Is Connected")
    else:
        print("Erorr!. Databsae Is Not Connected")
def newComponentButtonClicked(self):
    row = self.model.rowCount()
    self.model.insertRow(row)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After some try, I managed to solve part of my problem by subclassing QSqlRelationalTableModel:

```
class mysqlmodel(QSqlRelationalTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

    def setData(self, item, value, role):

        super().setData(item,value, role)
        a= item.siblingAtColumn(1).data()
        self.relationModel(2).setFilter("type_IDs like '"+a+"%'")
        return True
```

This works for my problem, but there are issues:

1. At first run,  if you want to change an item in combobox 2, it shows all options, but after modifications it shows just item belongs to item in combobox 1.
2. If you change an item in combobox 2 of row no 2, then you want to change an item in combobox 2 of row 3, it shows options for the "PREVIOUS" row unless you submit that(for example by pressing enter button or clicking somewhere else within the table)  and then automatically it changes to options for current row, and now you can select the right item.

Comment: Have you tested your code? I only get an empty table

Comment: @eyllanesc - this is simple code and yes its working. It is empty, but you can add items. If you click on the button above the table("add component") you can add some items and there you can see my problem. The part number name is not important. My problem is in next 2 columns

Comment: Okay, but I still have a question: You are assuming that the user will fill in the fields from left to right but let's say they don't and first click on the third column then what should be shown in that combobox?

Comment: @eyllanesc - In fact I didn't think about that, and I supposed that they are good gays and doing right things:)
by the way the answer could be just simply nothing or  the default value. That's not much important in my case. The only thing is important for me now is how to filter second combobox based on first combobox.

Comment: 1) The user is a free being who will not do what you think in many cases, 2) So I think I will assume that if an option was not selected from the combobox of the second column then the combobox of the third column will be empty.

Comment: I like to have everything clear before implementing or proposing a solution. I have one more doubt, let's say that the user selects an option in the second and third column, and then changes the option in the second column so that the value of the third column will no longer correspond to the correct value, then in that case what should it happen?

Comment: @eyllanesc - yes you are correct about user rights and I will consider it from now on. About your doubt, I think normally it would be in such way that when we select an option in combobox 1, necessarily we must have corespondent options in combobox 2 and one is selected by default, so if the user changes his/her mind the options in combobox2 will change automatically and he/she either must change selection in combobox 1 or chooses from options available in combobox2.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Hi. No answer??

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a qsqlrelationaltablemodel for combobox type at set up a relationship to the table with the name . when name is choosen filter model of combobox type.